# Why complex conjugate in definition of the Fourier transform?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group and $f:G \to \mathbb{C}$ a function. Its Fourier transform (when it exists) is defined to be
$$\widehat{f}(\chi) = \int_G f(g) \bar{\chi}(g) \mathrm{d} g,$$
Here $\chi \in \widehat{G} := \mathrm{Hom}(G, S^1)$ and $\mathrm{d} g$ is a choice of Haar measure on $G$.

Why does $\bar{\chi}$ appear and not $\chi$? Is this for historical reasons or is there a mathematical reason?

In practice one considers all characters $\chi$ at once (for example when performing Poisson summation), so it doesn't really make a difference including the complex conjugate in the definition.

Comment: this definition ensures that the Fourier transform is zero if $\chi\neq f$, which is a more convenient statement than $\bar{\chi}\neq f$

Comment: I'd say probably mostly historical - for example note that this way round ensures that the Fourier inversion formula looks like $f(x)=\int_{\widehat{G}}\widehat{f}(\chi)\chi(x) \mathrm{d}\chi$, so it depends whether you view the decomposition of $f$ into characters or the decomposition of $\widehat{f}$ into physical space as more fundamental. Also a reason for this convention is that then you can write $\widehat{f}(\chi)=\langle f,\chi\rangle$ (where we conjugate the second argument of the inner product for e.g. positivity reasons so $\langle f,f\rangle=\| f\|^2$).

Comment: I think when people do the fourier transform for noncommutative finite groups they often use the convention without complex conjugation

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, I do not think that [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444630/why-complex-conjugate-in-definition-of-the-fourier-transform#comment1148020_444630) is true.  Surely you meant the Fourier transform $\hat f(\chi)$ is *non*-$0$ if $\chi = f$?

Comment: The reason is that $\int f\overline{g}$ is an Hermitian dot product, while $\int fg$ is not.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1148053), @‍ThomasBloom also [suggested this](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1148021), but also pointed out that, whichever way you do it, either the transform or its inverse is going to be complex-conjugate-less, so I think this just shifts the question to: why the transform? (To which the answer is surely, .)  One might also consider modular, or even just $\overline{\mathbb Q_\ell}$, representation theory, in which setting there is no natural analogue of conjugation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an $L^2$ product: consider for instance the most classical Fourier expansion of $\mathbb Z$ periodic functions (or distributions) of one real variable.
You have for $f$ locally square integrable
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}\langle f, e_k\rangle_{L^2} e_k(x),
$$
that is
$
f(x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}\left(\int_0^1 f(y){e^{-2iπ ky}} dy\right) e^{2iπ kx},
$
simply since
$
\langle f, e_k\rangle_{L^2}=\int_0^1 f(y)\overline{e_k(y)}dy.
$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this nicely combines some of the points raised in the comments regarding the relation to inner products and the lack of minus sign present in the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Incidently a version of my question is also raised on signal processing stack exchange: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19004/why-is-a-negative-exponent-present-in-fourier-and-laplace-transform