# Harmonic analysis of vector bundles on symmetric spaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, symmetric-spaces

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445029).
Given a semisimple symmetric space $M\simeq G/H$, in particular, the real hyperbolic space $H_{p,q}\simeq SO(p,q)/SO(p,q-1)$, and a vector bundle $E$ over $M$ (for simplicity let's consider only the tensor bundles), the $L^{2}$-sections of $E$ constitute an unitary representation $\rho_{E}$ of $G$.

I'd like to know if the decomposition of $\rho_{E}$ into unitary irreps of $G$ has been studied or not, at least for the real hyperbolic space.

If not, can the spherical function method (see e.g. the explanations in [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445029)) be generalized to the case of vector bundles?

For the second question, I found in [Harmonic Analysis for Vector Fields on Hyperbolic Spaces](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01159971) that the authors have generalized this method to the tangent bundle case, but completeness is ensured by a Jacobi transform.

Comment: You only get a representation of $G$ on the sections, if the bundle is homogeneous, that is, induced by a finite-dimensional representation $\tau$  of $H$. For the representation of $G$ to be unitary, $\tau$ needs to be unitary, but there aren't that many finite dimensional unitary reps of $H$, unless $H$ is compact, i.e., $q=1$.